# Jquery script not working without alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I remove the alert from the function, the script doesn't work anymore.

Any ideas about why it happens ?

**Function with alert in front:**

```
function conScroll(getID){
    alert();
    $('#con_'+getID).mCustomScrollbar({
        theme: 'minimal',
        autoHideScrollbar: true,
        axis: 'y',
        mouseWheelPixels: 250,
        advanced:{ 
            updateOnContentResize: true 
        }
    });
}

$(document).on('click', 'a[id=cWin]', function(){
    var ID = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
    var TITLE = jQuery(this).attr('title');
    var PAGE = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').append('<div id="'+ ID +'" class="draggable">'+
                    '<div class="moveband">'+
                        '<div class="title">'+ TITLE +'</div>'+
                        '<div id="buttons">'+
                            '<div id="m_'+ ID +'" class="minimize"></div>'+
                            '<div id="c_'+ ID +'" class="close"></div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div style="clear:both"></div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div id="con_'+ ID +'" class="draggcon">d</div>'+
                '</div>');
    $('#list').append('<div id="t_'+ ID +'" class="item">Chatbox #'+ ID +'</div>'); 
    $('#con_' + ID).load('../php/' + PAGE + '.php');
    WinControl();
    conScroll(ID);
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Use call back of load i.e. `$('#con_' + ID).load('../php/' + PAGE + '.php', function(){});`

Comment: It work's, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add mCustomScrollbar initialization into settimeout. It will work.

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $('#con_'+getID).mCustomScrollbar({
    theme: 'minimal',
    autoHideScrollbar: true,
    axis: 'y',
    mouseWheelPixels: 250,
    advanced:{ 
        updateOnContentResize: true 
    }
});
}, 1000);
```